# How do I call ExternalProject output binary from cmake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I'm trying to use following approach to embed flatbuffers into my project:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    googleflatbuf
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/flatbuffers"
    GIT_TAG "v1.12.0"
    PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googleflatbuf"
    INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

flatbuf is built as expected, so there's no problems here.
Next I try to use it for actual code generation like that:

```
file(GLOB PROTOCOL_SRC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.fbs")

string (REPLACE ";" " " PROTOCOL_SRC_STR "${PROTOCOL_SRC}")

add_custom_target(
    protocol_src_gen
        COMMAND "${FLATC} --cpp -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${PROTOCOL_SRC_STR}"
        DEPENDS googleflatbuf
        SOURCES ${PROTOCOL_SRC}
)
```

Where `FLATC` is `"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/flatc"`
I'm sure that wouldn't be the best way to get flatc path even if it worked. In reality I get `FLATC ==  ../bin/flatc`.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. How do I get absolute path of `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`?
2. What is the right way to call executables built by ExternalProject?

Comment: Yes, that way should work (assuming you remove double quotes around parameters after `COMMAND`). Have you tried it? "How do I get absolute path of `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`? - `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` is already an absolute path. Not sure what is a problem.

Comment: Yes, this works. Removing quotes helped. I still see flatc being called as ../bin/flatc, but it works. Not sure what happens here, but it might be that quoted string is treated as executable path as whole. Which would be quite strange. @Tsyvarev, write an answer pls, so I could accept it.